# Generating Right Censored Copula Data using R

Tags: r

I am using the following code to generate right censored survival data. However, whenever I am running this code, there is an error and I am unable to print my data frame as the R says "there is no 'dat' object found".

I do not know what is the problem, kindly help me with this!

The code is as follows:

```
    library(methods)
    library(copula)
    library(muhaz)
    library(foreach)
    library(survival)
    library (MASS)

tau = 0.2
nsample = 100
err_dist = "Normal"
generate.dat <- function(tau,nsample,err_dist)
  {
  C <- rexp(nsample, rate = 0.8) # Censoring

  cc <- claytonCopula(copClayton@iTau(tau))
  u <- rCopula(nsample, cc)

  e <- qnorm(u,mean=0,sd=1) # Error term

  b1 <- 0.5 ; b2 <- 0.2  # using the old betas 
  beta <- matrix(c(b1, 0, 0, b2), 2) # as Beta got to be 2x2

  RHO <- 0  # Indpendence
  MU1 <- 0; S1 <- 1 # Std. Normal
  MU2 <- 0; S2 <- 1 # Std. Normal
  MU <- c(MU1, MU2) # mean vector
  SIGMA <- matrix (c(S1^2, S1*S2*RHO, S1*S2*RHO, S2^2), 2) # Var-Covar matrix
  Z <- mvrnorm(nsample, mu=MU, Sigma=SIGMA)

  T <- exp(-Z%*%beta + e)
  T1 <- T[,1]
  T2 <- T[,2]

  x1 <- pmin(T1,C)
  x2 <- pmin(T2,C); 
  d1 <- ifelse(T1<=C, 1, 0)
  d2 <- ifelse(T2<=C, 1, 0)

  dat <- data.frame(x1, x2, d1, d2)  
  return(dat)
  print(dat)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code without any errors. Are you running the function like this?

```
dat = generate.dat(tau, nsample, err_dist)
```

If you wanted the function to print `dat` every time, then put the `print` statement before the `return` (generally, the `return` statement should always the last thing in a function).

Comment: Yes, I did not know that part! Thanks